# If I demoted my arena, can I buy a chest by purchase right away?

Tags: clash-royale

In clash royale, if I'm in arena 10, for example, I want to demote to arena 9. My question is, if I demote to arena 9, can I buy a legendary chest by purchase in the shop right away?

Comment: Needs confirmation - Legendary chests can appear below arena 10, but legendary cards will not

Comment: Due to a recent update I believe it's no longer possible to drop from your current arena, unless you are over 4k.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because legendary chests are only available in level 10. Besides, the newest update has made it impossible to demote from arenas. For example, when your trophies are 500, and the arena trophy requirements are 500, then when you lose, your won't get any loss on trophies.

Answer (score 0):

Your arena does not restrict you in any way when buying chests. You can move around as much as you want trophies wise, and buy chests in the shop at the same time.

Comment: I am unsure of whether or not this works for 10 to 9, because only arena 10 allows for legendary chests.